# Angular transclusion when using multiple components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngcontent

I have three components of following hierarchy:

```
<parent-component>
 <wrapper-layer>
   <inner-most>
   </inner-most>
 </wrapper-layer>
</parent-component>
```

Im confused on how to pass a component from `<parent-component>` to `<inner-most>` component Via `<wrapper-layer>`.

During the transclusion how do I avoid the passed component to be displayed in the `<wrapper-layer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no answers. This is how I got it done:

In `<parent-component>`:  Place the component you wish to pass.

In `<wrapper-layer>`: Use the following snippet:

```
<ng-container ngProjectAs="component-to-pass">
            <ng-content select="component-to-pass"></ng-content>
</ng-container>
```

In `<inner-most>`: `<ng-content select="component-to-pass"></ng-content>`.

By doing this way, the passed component does not get rendered in the middle layer but instead gets passed into the `<inner-most>` component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a component to it's children, then you can use something like this:

in parent-component html:

```
<wrapper-layer [parent]="this">...
```

(this will pass the current component to it's children. Or, if you want to find a custom component, still can use a [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) selector )

in wrapper-layer ts:

```
@Input() parent: any;
```

and you just pass it again, in wrapper-layer html:

```
<inner-most [parent]="parent">...
```

Comment: It is not an object. I want to pass an actual component to inner-most. It can be done using <ng-content>. I can do it up to one layer but I am not really sure how it happens when there is an additional layer.

Comment: That is component interaction with input binding.